# Can a power series of $x$ converge to $\log(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, taylor-expansion, power-series

I found the following equation, to solve for $\{c_k\}$, with $0<x<1$:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k = \log x $$

I know that $\log x$ does not have a Taylor series expansion around $x=0$.
Does this mean that no $\{c_k\}$ can be found such that the equality holds?

Note that the equality is not required to hold for $x=0$, where $\log x$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that no $\{c_k\}$ can be found such that the equality holds?

Exactly.  If it would hold for some $x \neq 0$, then it would also hold for any $z$ with $|z| < |x|$.  As it is a power series, this would mean that $\ln$ is analytic on the disc $|z|<|x|$ which is not the case because $\ln x$ has a singularity at $x=0$.  Not even a radius of convergence of $0$ would work because $\ln 0$ is not defined.

And not even a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) does work, because if such a series converged on some annulus around $0$, it would be analytic there.  But you would hit a branch cut somewhere.

Comment: For a proof of "converge for some $x\neq 0$, also converges $\forall z$ with $|z|<|x|$" see the proof of Note 10.1.1 in [this link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/10%3A_Power_Series/10.1%3A_Power_Series_and_Functions). This bit is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!